# Own theme for Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I'm annoyed by the default "theme" of Wikipedia on a PC or Laptop - since its long lines are hard to read. Is there a way to set an own theme for Wikipedia to shrink the displayed width and thereby the line length to a readable length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Preferences / Appearance and disable the "Use Legacy Vector" option.